# Chrome/Safari and inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

So I have a few elements in an inline-block which display perfectly as they should in Firefox but for some reason in Safari and Chrome the positioning is all off

**CSS:**

```
#bb-tools {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.main-tools {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
}

.main-tools a img.icon-space { margin-right: 5px; }

.main-tools a {
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.main-tools a:hover {
    color: #f4cdd4;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.search-box-responsive {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bb-tools">
  <div class="main-tools"> <a rel="nofollow" href="#"><span class="login">Log In</span></a> <a href="#"><span class="help">Help</span></a> <a class="basket" rel="nofollow" href="#"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/20x23" width="18" height="20" style="display:inline-block; border:0;" alt="" /> <span class="basket-contents"> <span class="basket-count"><sup> (100) </sup></span></span></a>
    <div class="search-box-responsive">
      <form class="search-responsive" role="search" method="get" action="#">
        <fieldset>
          <input id="headerSearch" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
          <input id="headerSearch" value="" type="submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle, if opened in Firefox, displays as it should:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4tjJt/)**

Can someone explain? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening as none of your anchors are floated so it is pushing the form down to the next line before it can get floated.

If you wrap your anchors in a `div` and then add `float:right` to that div, it should fix your problem

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4tjJt/4/)

Comment: Why is this not happening in firefox?

Comment: Yeah, I get why this works, but I don't understand how this wouldn't effect firefox too?

Comment: Browsers handle floating differently, I think it's to do with the flow of the document. I think firefox must apply the float first and then render the rest of the none floating elements where as chrome probably renders the elements in the order they appear then apply the float after - but I'm not sure about this

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what is causing the issue since i didn't get what you're trying to achieve with the css.

If you just want to fix the issue, you can place the `.search-box-responsive` before the links in `DOM`, if possible.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tjJt/3/) (*tested in safari and chrome*)

*sidenote: float has no effect on absolutely possible elements, as far as i know.*

Answer (score 1):

Add `.search-box-responsive` div right after `#bb-tools` div as in

http://jsfiddle.net/4tjJt/2/